# Check to see if an array element already exists

Tags: javascript

I have implemented function to add a name to an array which then will be displayed into a table on a page.

The next question I have is, how do I check whether a first and last name already exist in the array. My function is below, once I know how to handle the check I will add it to the function.

```
function addNewGuest(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    let f = document.querySelector("#first_name").value
    let l = document.querySelector("#last_name").value
    let names = getGuestList()

    if (f || l) {
        alert("First and Last name required.")
    }
    
    if (f && l) {
        let name = { fName: f, lName: l }
        names.push(name)
        localStorage.setItem('names', JSON.stringify(names))
    }
    displayGuestList()
    document.querySelector("#first_name").value = ''
    document.querySelector("#last_name").value = ''
}
```

Comment: Have you tried googling "Check to see if an array element already exists"? When I google that, the top link gives a good answer (with an example).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to search for a person, and if the `find` method returns `undefined`, that person doesn't exist, so we flip to boolean.

```js
const alreadyExists = names.find(({fName, lName}) => fName === f && lName === l) !== undefined;
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to loop over the array and check each element to make sure it exists.

An easy way to do so would be to use the [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) helper function on arrays.

```
// check if a name with the same first and last name already exists
function nameExists(input, namesList) {
  return namesList.some(name => (input.f === name.f) && (input.l === name.l);
}
```

However, looping over each item is pretty inefficient for very large datasets so you may be better off looking into using data structures like a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) or even a regular [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) which are tailored for looking up key/value pairs.